# Jquery attr not working Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the code below that clicking on an image hides a div.
Works perfectly, but does not work in IE ...

Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/mtsys/6qAfp/

codes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    $('.fechar').click( function() { alert('testes'); $(".nav").attr("hidden",true); });
    $('.mais').click( function() {
        var status = $(".nav").attr("hidden");
        if (status)
        {
            $(".nav").attr("hidden",false);
        }
        else
        {
            $(".nav").attr("hidden",true);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    Estágio    
    <div class="mais"></div>
</div>
<div class ="parent">     
    <div class="content">        
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav"><div class="fechar"></div><div id="dadosDiv"></div></div>   
</div>
```

tks

Comment: What version of jQuery, what version of IE?

Comment: .attr("hidden")? what exactly is that supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.hide()` and `toggle()` to change the display of the elements

```
$('.fechar').click(function () {
    $(".nav").hide()
});
$('.mais').click(function () {
    $(".nav").toggle()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j44PF/)

Comment: ... as `hidden` attribute isn't [supported](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/01/09/html5-hidden-attribute-browser-support/) by IE10-. Besides, it's technically not its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Why not change your JS to:

```
    $('.fechar').click( function() { alert('testes'); $(".nav").hide(); });
    $('.mais').click( function() {
        $(".nav").toggle();
    });
```

This will not only simplify your code but utilise jQuery's inbuilt function for toggling content visibility. Incidentally, the issue was the `hidden` `attr` reference, this should have been `.css('hidden',true)` if you want to go down that route...